# Accessing component scope within template block

Tags: ember.js

if I have a component called `my-scope` which is defined only as:

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
    foo: 'bar'
})
```

and then I use the component in a template, like so:

```
{{#my-scope}}
    {{foo}}
{{/my-scope}}
```

How can I reach the scope of the surrounding block component? I have tried:

- `{{foo}}`
- `{{component.foo}}`
- `{{view.foo}}`

Maybe this is a case where I need to use a view? Hoping not but maybe that is the case.

> note: my use-case is far more complex but let's just say that normal binding approach to components `{{#my-scope foo=outsideFoo}} ... {{/my-scope}}` is not a workable example

Comment: The block format specifically drops you out of the component scope and into the parent scope, there isn't any available link from the parent scope into the component due to the isolation level.  The only way to do it would be to have the component register itself with the parent (giving the parent an opportunity to have a reference to the component) then use the parent's reference to then show foo some magical way.

Comment: Thanks @Kingpin2k, i was afraid magic, indirection, and hackiness might be involved. I assume though that if I used a view it *would* work, right?

Comment: {{view.foo}} looks like it will work from within a view...

Comment: I'm actually surprised by that, it shifts you outside of the scope, except the view stays in scope... http://emberjs.jsbin.com/celijexiku/1/edit...

Comment: Awesome. That will help but I am worried that Views will be going away. Not sure how to replicate this functionality in a Ember 2.0 compliant way. :(

Comment: Isn’t this what [block params](http://emberjs.com/blog/2014/12/08/ember-1-9-0-released.html#toc_block-params) are for?

Comment: @BuckDoyle thank you, that's the way to go for me.

Comment: Yes that's what I'm using today. Can't remember if it want available in Jan or I wasn't aware of it.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your specific use-case, it's hard to know if the following answer will work for you, but one thing is for sure - it is very much compliant with Ember 2.0 "data down, actions up" philosophy (see [this](http://www.samselikoff.com/blog/data-down-actions-up/) excellent piece by Sam Selikoff).

You can create a component that sends an action up with the data that you want available in your surrounding context as follows:

```
App.XTestComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  foo: 'bar',

  didInsertElement: function(){
    this.sendAction('action', this.get('foo'));
  }
});
```

Then, in your surrounding context (controller), you can catch the action and set the appropriate data:

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  foo: 'controller',
  actions: {
    setFoo: function(param){
      this.set('foo', param);
    }
  }
});
```

Now, you can use your `foo` variable in the surrounding context the way you showed in the example:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
  {{#x-test action='setFoo'}} Hmm {{ foo }} {{/x-test}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" id='components/x-test'>
  <h2>Testing</h2>
  {{ yield }}
</script>
```

See a working example [here](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/xupoho/1/edit?html,js,output)

(In theory, you can do this using an observer and not just from inside `didInsertElement`, but I have not tested it.)

Comment: Ok I'm intrigued but I tried this modified version of your JSBIN and it doesn't seem to provide localised scope to the block: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/yezun/2/ ... I think I'm still not full getting this approach.

Comment: You mean because it's ALWAYS showing the value of `foo` from the component? That's because once the `foo` property gets reset in the controller it becomes the new value everywhere. Are you saying you want `foo` to be one thing inside the block and another outside of the block? Not sure that's possible with this approach

Comment: Yes I want "block scope"

Comment: According to this approach, "block scope" gets triggered in the component, but ultimately it is achieved by setting the property on the controller who called the component... Hopefully, my other answer would work for you if this one does not

Answer (score 0):

You can use `_view.parentView` to access the value of `foo` property inside the component. (Because there is an underscore in `_view`, to me that means that it's not public API, so they might get rid of it in the future - but it's around for now :))

Something like the following:

```
{{#x-test}} Inside c1: {{ _view.parentView.foo.name }} {{/x-test}}
```

Working demo [here](http://jsbin.com/cubesa/2/edit?html,js,output)