# EmberJS 1.13.3 / Component / Block template / access component property

Tags: templates, ember.js, components

I'm using Ember 1.13.3 (latest one as of 2015-07-16).

I have a component defined this way:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  tagName: 'li',
  yow: 'argh',
});
```

It's corresponding hbs is simple (the default):

```
{{yield}}
```

I use the component this way (in my application.hbs):

```
{{#side-menuitem name='medium' current=selectedMenuItem clicked='menuItemSelected'}}
  {{#link-to name}}Hey you ... {{yow}}{{/link-to}}
{{/side-menuitem}}
```

I'm expectint to see a link with label: Hey you ... argh.
But I get: Hey you ... (without argh).

There's a similar thread here: [Accessing component scope within template block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28013503/accessing-component-scope-within-template-block)

I tried also: {{view.yow}} and {{component.yow}}, no luck.
Looks like Ember 1.13 (still) has this behavior: The block format specifically drops you out of the component scope and into the parent scope, there isn't any available link from the parent scope into the component due to the isolation level.

This is undesirable..., and I somehow I thought that behavior has been changed in 1.13 (toward compatibility with 2.0), but I'm not seeing it (or I thought wrong?).

How to get around this without messing up with the (parent) controller?

Thanks,
Raka

Answer (score 1):

This should work, just change your templates to:

```
// application.hbs
{{#side-menuitem name='medium' current=selectedMenuItem clicked='menuItemSelected' as |yow|}}
  {{#link-to name}}Hey you ... {{yow}}{{/link-to}}
{{/side-menuitem}}

// component.hbs
{{yield yow}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You kind of answered your own question, this is just how block components work. If your needs allow you to use this component in non-block form, then it will work the way you want:

template:

```
// side-menuitem.hbs
<li>
  {{#link-to name}}Hey you ... {{yow}}{{/link-to}}
</li>
```

script:

```
// side-menuitem.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  yow: 'argh'
});
```

use:

```
{{side-menuitem name='index' current=selectedMenuItem clicked='menuItemSelected'}}
```

If you *do* need to keep it as a block, then the suggestions from the other post you found are the way to go (data down, action up). You can send the value up to the parent controller  using `sendAction` and have an action in the parent controller to catch it and manipulate it as needed.